# Why does compiling small dependent rust code take so long?

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-polars

I have a tiny rust code (actually one main.rs file) that depends on the [Polars Library](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) code.
However the compilation time for every minor change is huge - around 5-7 minutes.
I use VSCode via wsl in Windows, along side the rust-analyzer extension.

This is my `main.rs` file content:

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let s: Series = Series::new("employees", &vec!["Mahmoud", "Barak", "Ferris"]);
    println!("{:?}", s.reverse());
}
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file with Polars' dependency:

```
[package]
name = "barak_test"
version.workspace = true
authors.workspace = true
edition.workspace = true
homepage.workspace = true
repository.workspace = true
license.workspace = true


[dependencies]
polars = { path = "../../crates/polars", features = ["lazy", "csv", "ipc"] }
```

I also switched `rust-analyzer.checkOnSave` off on the `Setting.json` file, and verified that only my file is being recompiled:

```
warning: unused import: `coerce::*`
  --> crates/polars-plan/src/dsl/functions/mod.rs:19:9
   |
19 | pub use coerce::*;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

warning: unused import: `index::*`
  --> crates/polars-plan/src/dsl/functions/mod.rs:24:9
   |
24 | pub use index::*;
   |         ^^^^^^^^

warning: unused variable: `expr_arena`
   --> crates/polars-plan/src/logical_plan/optimizer/predicate_pushdown/utils.rs:151:5
    |
151 |     expr_arena: &Arena<AExpr>,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_expr_arena`
    |
    = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: `polars-plan` (lib) generated 3 warnings (run `cargo fix --lib -p polars-plan` to apply 3 suggestions)
   Compiling barak_test v0.35.4 (/mnt/d/PycharmProjects/polars/examples/barak_test)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 7m 21s
```

Any idea what can be the problem?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Using `cargo build --timings` yields exactly the data besides the `Total Time` section, the generated graph is empty.

Comment: You can get a better understanding of what cargo does and when using [`cargo build --timings`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/cargo/reference/timings.html)

Comment: I'd first check `rust-analyzer` does not mess with the build cache of `cargo build` (might happen if they are different versions / nightly vs. stable / …)

Comment: @cafce25 already check - the log says only one file ie being compiled

Comment: If `--timings` does not yield any insights, you can go deeper and [use rustc's self-profiling](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/why-is-my-rust-build-so-slow#rustc-self-profiling). via `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Zself-profile`.

Comment: Have you tried running `cargo clean` and seeing if problem persists?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I get the same output